# Integral over a curve in the sphere

Tags: integration, differential-geometry

Fix $r\in(0,2)$, and consider arbitrary points $\mathbf{x},\mathbf{q}\in\mathbf{S}^2\subseteq\mathbf{R}^{3}$ such that $q_z > 1-r$ and $x_z > 1-r$. Consider the path $\gamma:[0,2\pi)\to\mathbf{S}^2$ given by $$\gamma(t)=(R\cos(t),R\sin(t),1-r),$$ where $R=\sqrt{r(2-r)}$. I want to compute $$\int_{\gamma([0,2\pi])}\frac{\ln(1-\mathbf{y}\cdot\mathbf{q})}{1-\mathbf{x}\cdot\mathbf{y}}~d\ell(\mathbf{y}).$$
I've been having a lot of trouble actually working this out by hand, and I'm not sure if there are any clever techniques that I could use to evaluate the above expression. I came across this integral when working out a representation formula for a solution to some sort of Dirichlet problem, and it would be very nice to have a closed form expression of the above.

If there isn't any nice closed form solution for such an expression, any ideas on numerical techniques for computing the above integral *quickly* would be also appreciated.

Comment: $x$ and $q$ are essentially two parameters. Have you tried to use the definition of line integral?

Comment: I understand that $x$ and $q$ are just two parameters. I also did use the definition of the line integral to expand it out as a definite integral from $0$ to $2\pi$, and that's where I've actually been having trouble evaluating the integral.

Answer (score 0):

First, consider your sphere as a subset of the Riemann sphere, then take the inverse transformation to take your curve from the sphere to the complex plane, then compute the line integral as usual.